# How to fix invoke uiautomator from command Prompt

Tags: jvm, appium, android-uiautomator, inspect-element

I want to run `uiautomatorviewer` from command Prompt.

But it gives an error:

> -Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use
>   -classpath instead.
>       Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>       Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Please guide.

Comment: have you set the environment variables for android home or not ?

Comment: Can you share the command you are running?

Comment: I have the same problem. Typing cmd from C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin , then uiautomatorviewer.bat in the command line window. My JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1 and JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231 .

Answer (score 0):

1. Download JDK 8 version & install it
2. Set Environment variable as `[JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65]`
3. `Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin & %JAVA_HOME%\lib`
   and provide `uiautomatorviewer.bat` command in cmd

The above scenario  will work.